# Loading an image from a URL but displaying it progressively

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a screen that will load around 5 images, but they are huge images.  Right now I use a

```
NSURLRequest
```

and a:

```
 connectionDidFinishLoading
```

..for callback to tell me when each image is loaded.

The problem is that images would pop up one by one. Is there a way to have it display the image while it loads?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The guts of what you need to do this are available as CGImageSource methods.

First, you use an asynchronous NSURLConnection to get the data. You add received data to a NSMutableData object as it arrives, so the data object gets bigger and bigger til finished.

You also create a progressive image source:

```
CGImageSourceRef imageSourcRef = CGImageSourceCreateIncremental(dict);
```

You will find lots of examples here and on google how to set the dictionary required.

Then as the data arrives, you pass the TOTAL data object into this method:

```
CGImageSourceUpdateData(imageSourcRef, (__bridge CFDataRef)data, NO); // No means not finished
```

You can then ask the image source for an image, which will be partial as the image is downloading. With a CGImage you can create a UIImage.

When you get the final data, you update the image source on last time:

```
CGImageSourceUpdateData(imageSourcRef, (__bridge CFDataRef)data, YES);
```

You then use the image source to get a final image and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Displaying it while loading ,I don't think `UIImageView` can load `UIImages`with incomplete data  while loading.I will go for 
 [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) ,
It can deal with all the burden of loading image asynchronous.Also `UIActivityIndicator` is already added to it.So it will be more user friendly

Comment: I need it to display while it loads say if it download half of the single image, it will display half and so on. I don't think this does it.  I know already how to download it without blocking, is just I need it to display partially while it downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Use blocks and GCD's dispatch_async method.

Look at this example:

```
//communityDetailViewController.h
```

@interface communityDetailViewController : UIViewController {

```
UIImageView *imgDisplay;
UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;

// the dispatch queue to load images
dispatch_queue_t queue;
```

}

@end

//communityDetailViewController.m

```
- (void)loadImage
```

{

```
[activity startAnimating];

NSString *url = @"URL the image";

if (!queue) {
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("image_queue", NULL);
}

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [activity stopAnimating];
        activity.hidden = YES;
        if (anImage != nil) {
            [imgDisplay setImage:anImage];
        }else{
            [imgDisplay setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_available.png"]];
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: I need it to display while it loads say if it download half of the single image, it will display half and so on. I don't think this does it.  I know already how to download it without blocking, is just I need it to display partially while it downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UIImageView` and use this.

```
  -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
    {
        imageData = [NSMutableData data];
        imageSize = [response expectedContentLength];
        imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateIncremental(NULL);
    }

        -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
        {
            [imageData appendData:data];

             CGImageSourceUpdateData(imageSource, (__bridge CFDataRef)imageData, ([imageData length] == imageSize) ? true : false);
            CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(imageSource, 0, NULL);
            if (cgImage){
                UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
                dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    self.image = img;
                });
                CGImageRelease(cgImage);
            }
    }
```